# Is there an functionality in HTML5 to discover client internet connection type?

Tags: html, wifi, internet-connection

Is there a way for an HTML5 web-app to discover the connection-type on the client? (Something similar to, say, Apple's reachability class)

I want to mainly check whether the connection is a GPRS/EDGE/3G/... versus a WiFi, with certain kinds of data uploads only happening when the connection is over WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No html5 doesn't support it . You can instead check the time it takes to send and receive a file to know the users speed

Comment: Thanks. Don't need to know the speed, just whether underlying connection is wifi or mobile network (out of consideration towards data costs for user).

Comment: time that it takes will let you know what type of content to show